# looping through array from user input

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have a form with a select field which has the day of the week, I already have the days in an array

```
$weekdays = array("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday");
```

and I am populating the select using

```
<select name="weekday">
                    <?php
                    foreach ($weekdays AS $weekday) {
                        PRINT '<option value="' . $weekday . '">' . $weekday . '</option>';
                    }
                    ?>
                </select>
```

I am now trying to create a response page where it will print out the next three week days after the one that is selected but I am unsure how to, I currently only have

```
$weekdays = array("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday");
foreach($weekdays as $value){ 
    echo $value . "<br />\n";
```

I know I will have to collect the value of the user input from the form but I dont know what I do once I have it so for example

```
$weekday = $_POST['weekday'];
```

Comment: Well I think the best way is just to start with some code

Comment: Show some code how you are doing?

Comment: @Rizier123 This is fixable with the code provided now. He wants to have `$_POST['weekday']` compare it with the array and then take the next 3 results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `array_keys` to find the keys of the next values to parse, and check if you're going to far to reset your parsing to Monday :

```
$receivedDay = 'Saturday';
$weekdays = array("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday");

for ($i = 1; $i < 4; $i++) {
  $key = array_keys($weekdays, $receivedDay);
  $key = $i + $key[0];
  if ($key > 6) {
    $key -= 7;
  }
  echo $weekdays[$key] . PHP_EOL; // Or <br>
}
```

Output

```
Sunday
Monday
Tuesday
```

Comment: I was previously thinking of just adding an extra Monday and Tuesday to the array because I was unsure how to reset it

Answer (score 0):

This should be your php code
Change frontend this way

```
<select name="weekday">
                    <?php
                    foreach ($weekdays AS $weekdayKey=>$weekdayValue) {
                        PRINT '<option value="' . $weekdayKey . '">' . $weekdayValue . '</option>';
                    }
                    ?>
                </select>
```

Here 5 stands for saturday Send index appropriately from frontend

```
 <?php 
    $array = array('Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday','Sunday');
    $total = count($array);
    $sel =5;
    for($i=0;$i<3;$i++) {
        $sel = $sel+1;
        if($sel>=$total){
            $sel = $sel-$total;
        }
        $getDays [] = $array[$sel];
     }
     echo "<pre>";
        print_r($getDays);
     echo "</pre>"; 
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

the first step is put your select inside a `<form>`

```
<form action="request.php">
   <select name="weeks">
         foreach here
   </select>
</form>
```

Put the content inside a new file `request.php` at the same folder

```
<?php
    $weekName = $_REQUEST['weekday'];
    // Your logic about $weekName
    echo $weekName;
?>
```